# AVPlayer removeTimeObserver crashes app (swift 3)

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, avplayer, key-value-observing

I have global variable time observer set as:

```
self.timeObserver = self.avPlayer?.addPeriodicTimeObserver(forInterval: CMTime(seconds: 0.5, preferredTimescale: CMTimeScale(NSEC_PER_SEC)), queue: DispatchQueue.main) { [weak self] time in
      guard let weakSelf = self else {
          return
      }
      // updating label with time
}
```

when view is getting closed I call:

```
if self.avPlayer != nil {
   self.avPlayer!.removeTimeObserver(self.timeObserver)
}
```

but that crashes the app saying:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'You did not supply a reference
>   to an object returned by either
>   -addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval:queue:usingBlock: or -addBoundaryTimeObserverForTimes:queue:usingBlock:'

Please tell me what am I doing wrong? Thank You

Comment: Could you check that your `avPlayer` is not nil when you add a periodic time observer?

Comment: if self.avPlayer != nil { self.avPlayer!.removeTimeObserver(self.timeObserver) } I am checking that and no, it is not nil

Comment: Is the line with `addPeriodicTimeObserver` executed just once?

Comment: yes, just when I initialize the avplayer

Comment: Looks like self.timeObserver is null after the init.
So verify that this line is being run at least once, and that you do receive an object.

Comment: The self.timeObserver is not nil

Comment: @virusss8 could you please check the address of `self.timeObserver` when you add it and when you remove it? To see if it's the same object.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to unwrap `self.timeObserver`.

`removeTimeObserver()` takes in `Any` object, but you are passing in `Any?`, which causes the crash.